# Google App Engine - Task dependency

Tags: google-app-engine

In my application, I have a long task, so I split it into n smaller tasks. After these n tasks complete, another one task is to be performed and it depends on the results of those n tasks. How do I achieve this dependency with Task API? i.e. perform one task after other n tasks.

Comment: Found a question similar to yours.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224564/calling-a-script-after-tasks-queue-is-empty

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 methods that can solve this problem.
Suppose the task TD depends on n other tasks TA, and there is a queue Q.

1. Push n TA tasks in to queue Q. When each task TA finishes, it checks if itself is the last one in the queue Q. If a TA is the last task in queue Q, it pushes TD to queue Q.
2. Push n TA tasks and TD to queue Q. When TD run, it checks if all TA task finish. If there is any TA unfinished, TD cancels its execution by returning any HTTP status code outside of the range 200-299.

The key of these methods is to get number of tasks in the queue Q. Although I haven't tried, I know there is a Python API provides an experimental method to get TaskQueue resource of a specific queue. The stats.totalTasks property is the total number of queues in the queue.

Please see http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the [GAE Pipeline API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/), it is used to build complex task workflow like the one you described.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach could be to start by adding all tasks to the queue. Have the N initial tasks log info to the datastore upon completion, in some manner that allows you to query the datastore to see if they have all run.
When the dependent task runs, it performs this datastore query to see if its conditions are met (checks that all initial tasks have logged that they are finished). If not, it needs to run later.
To accomplish this, the dependent task could add a copy of itself to the queue, scheduled to run after some given time interval.  Alternately (as in the answer above), the dependent task could terminate with an error status code, in which case it will be automatically retried at some later point, as long as the retry_limit for the queue or the task is not exceeded.